# I have an 8-hour layover in Rome. Can I go out of the airport with a Schengen single-entry visa?

Tags: schengen, international-travel, layovers, rome, prague

I have a business trip in the Czech Republic and my visa has been approved with one entry only. I would like to ask if by any chance I can go out of the airport and explore Rome a little bit as I have an 8-hour layover on my way back to Manila from Prague. Since I only have 1 entry, does that mean that if my passport has been stamped with exit when leaving Prague, then I don't have a chance to go out in Rome even just for a layover?

Comment: If I understand your plans, you will fly Prague to Rome, then Rome to Manila. The Prague to Rome flight is inside the Schengen zone. Why do you expect your passport to be stamped on leaving Prague?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  You seem to have created two accounts (https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/68176/ristiane-esporas and https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/68197/ristiane11).  You can [merge](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) them.

Answer (score 12):

For flights within the Schengen area, visas don't matter. You can fly between Rome and Prague a dozen times if you want, and exit the airport every time, as well as any other airport in the Schengen area. Only when you board the flight from Rome (or anywhere in Schengen) to *outside* Schengen area will your visa be used up as you exited.

The same is true on arrival: your visa is checked when you arrive at any airport inside Schengen - here Rome. From then on, you can fly around as you like.